# How to add onChange method for uiselectmultiple element in angular-schema-form

Tags: json, checkbox, onchange, angular-schema-form

I can add multiple items into a dropdown in [Angular Schema Form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form) using the following schema and form.

```
var schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "model": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}

var form = [
    {
        key: "model",
        type: "uiselectmultiple",
        titleMap: {
            "Model 1", "model_1",
            "Model 2", "model_2",
            "Model 3", "model_3"
        },
        onChange: changeValues(modelValue, form)
    }   
];
```

The `onChange` method doesn't fire when selecting an item from the list.
I followed [this solution](https://github.com/OptimalBPM/angular-schema-form-dynamic-select/issues/98) and still didn't get the expected result.

I can use checkboxes instead of using multi-selection. But then I would have to remove the "X" mark, "+add" button and additional header text from the checkboxes. [How to handle onChange with Angular Schema Form Checkbox boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792617/how-to-handle-onchange-with-angular-schema-form-checkbox-boolean)

Comment: Did you try the `$scope.$watch()` solution mentioned at the start of the solution issue post?

Comment: Can you please explain the way to use $scope.$watch?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch
Using the "function as watch expression" version, you can return the entire list of values using join and then it will trigger a change every time the list changes and there is a digest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check